# Does the Perl diamond operator iterate over non-magic arrays (not @ARGV)?

Tags: perl, arrays, diamond-operator

I don't think the following should work, but it does:

```
$ perl -e '@a = qw/1222 2 3/; while (<@a>) { print $_ ."\n";}'
1222
2
3
$
```

As far as I know, Perl's `<>` operator shoud work on filehandle, globs and so on, with the exception of the literal `<>` (instead of `<FILEHANDLE>`), which magically iterates over `@ARGV`.

Does anyone know if it's supposed to work also as it did in my test?

Comment: From perlop(1) about <> and @ARGV:

 THere’s how it works: the first time <> is evaluated, the @ARGV array is checked, and if it is empty, $ARGV[0] is set to
       "-", which when opened gives you standard input.  The @ARGV array is then processed as a list of filenames.

I can see something similar happening with my @a, though it doesn't seem as that should happen with every array (and I know the foreach or map are better ways to go about processing arrays).
I'd still like to know why without burrowing into the code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Magic at work!

From '[perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators)':

> If what's within the angle brackets is neither a filehandle nor a simple scalar variable
>   containing a filehandle name, typeglob, or typeglob reference, it is
>   interpreted as a filename
>   pattern to be globbed, and either a list of filenames or the next
>   filename in the list is
>   returned, depending on context.

This is the rule you're triggering with this code. Here's what's happening:

1. <@a> is (syntactically, at compile-time) determined to be a [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) expansion
2. thus <> turns @a into the string "1222 2 3" (string interpolation of an array)
3. [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)("1222 2 3") in list context returns ('1222', '2', '3')

Comment: OK, so I just got up, but I simply don't get #3.

Comment: The behavior is: unless there are pattern matching metacharacters in its argument, glob doesn't bother going to the filesystem.

This can be surprising. It helps me to think of it in terms of the shell glob functionality, which perl's glob aims to emulate: if you say 'cat foo', the shell invokes 'cat' with an argument of 'foo', regardless of whether 'foo' exists. If you say 'cat foo.*', the shell will call 'cat' with variable arguments, depending on what (if anything) matches the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

This is invoking [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html).

Answer (score -1):

> `<FH>` is not the name of a filehandle, but an angle operator that does a line-input operation on the handle. This confusion usually manifests itself when people try to print to the angle operator" - [Programming Perl](http://books.google.com/books?id=oh8lz4A3sUsC&dq=programming+perl&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=DtPoSq6dF8O0lAfOgsD_Bw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CB0Q6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=&f=false)

So in your case the array is a handle, which makes sense, and thus the operator iterates over it. So in answer to your question, yes, I think this is standard (but obscure) Perl. It is obscure because the language has more obvious ways to iterate over an array.

P.S. However, thanks for this, this will be great for code golf competitions.

Comment: Don't post links to unauthorized copies of books.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't even realise. Sorry for that one.

Comment: foreach(@a) is just as short and easy as while(<@a>), so it doesn't help much in code golf.

Comment: ...and `for(@a)` is exactly equivalent to `foreach(@a)`, but 4 characters shorter, which does help when golfing.